# Angular Observables Change local function variable from within subscription onSuccess => {}

Tags: angular, http, this, observable

So I'm trying to change the variable 'success' from within the success function callback after subscribing to the observable. I've debugged with the Chrome debugger after writing a test for it and failing to return true on a successful POST.

The test goes into the response => {} function but after stepping through "success = true", it is still false. Since I'll be doing this for various other functions I would prefer having a long list of class variables in order to refer to them with "this" as I've seen in various other examples. Is there a way to make success be true?

```
public login(username: string, password: string): boolean {
  let success = false;

  this.http.post<LoginResponse>('/api/login_check', {username: username, password: password}).subscribe(
    response => {
      success          = true;
      this.currentUser = new User(response.user);
      sessionStorage.setItem('userJWT', response.token);
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Login failed - ' + error);
    }
  );

  return success;
}
```

Comment: it because the response is asynchronous and method return success variable before http.post. It because login is synchronous and inside you call asynchonous function. You need login return observable and where you call login you need subscribe this method to return result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not mixed synchronous and asynchronous function to obtain the result.

Once you call anything async you need to wait for it, because it will happen outside of the thread.

This will work for example

**UserService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    login(username: string, password: string): Observable {
        return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error('Bad login!');
                }
            });
    }
}
```

**And elsewhere in your component**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
    login() {
        this.userService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                });
    }
}
```